# How to make text background blur in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have multiple Quotes in scroll view in form of text and image on background and i want to make view blur only for text not full image. Here is code :-

```
Text(text)
.padding(.trailing, 10)
.font(.custom(AppData.shared().appFont, size: 38))
.foregroundColor(.white)
.frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth, height: UIScreen.screenHeight)
.multilineTextAlignment(.center)
.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 7)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
.ignoresSafeArea()
```

**I want to blur text background instead of shadow.**

Comment: I also tried .blur(radius:1) property but it blurs the text not text background..

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`material`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material) with a `background` modifier.

```
Text(text)
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
```

You can also apply [`blur`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/blur(radius:opaque:)) modifier on `Rectangle` which you can set as `background` of your `Text`.

```
Text(text)
    .padding()
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .background(
         Rectangle()
            .fill(.gray.opacity(0.5))
            .blur(radius: 5)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for help but this is good to achieve shadow effect but unable to get blur effect.

Comment: From the apple documentation of **Material** "You can apply a blur effect to a view that appears behind another view by adding a material with the background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:) modifier:", this is blur not shadow also can you add visual represent of what you actually need